# logstash timestamp date filter

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I would like to change the @timestamp to the time from one of my fields

I have a field called Time which has the time I want to use for the @timestamp. This time though is in an inconvenient format "dd-MM-yyyy_HHmmss" The time is "05-JAN-2016_150345". I would like to change this format into something like ISO and make it my @timestamp but so far, my date filter fails. Please help.

```
  date
  {
    match => [ "Time" , "dd-MM-yyyy_HHmmss" ]
    target => "@timestamp"
  }
```

Comment: Try with `MMM` for the month. From the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html): "MMM
    abbreviated month text. Example: Jan for January."